# JavaScript Number Guessing Game - Issue with End of Game Logic

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple number guessing game using HTML and JavaScript. The game provides the user with 10 attempts to guess a randomly generated number between 0 and 50. The user inputs their guess, clicks "Sprawdź" (Check), and receives feedback on whether the guess is too high, too low, or correct.

```js
var liczba = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);

function check() {
  let prob = document.getElementById('prob');
  if (prob.value == 0) return;
  let strzal = document.getElementById('liczba');
  let txt = document.getElementById('res');
  if (!strzal.value) txt.innerText = "Wprowadź liczbę!";
  else if (strzal.value == liczba) {
    prob.value = 0;
    strzal.value = '';
    txt.innerText = "Wygrałeś";
    return;
  } else if (strzal.value > liczba) txt.innerText = "Za dużo";
  else if (strzal.value < liczba) txt.innerText = "Za mało";
  prob.value -= 1;
  if (prob.value == 0) txt.innerText = "Koniec gry";
}

function giveUp() {
  document.getElementById('res').innerText = liczba;
  document.getElementById('prob').value = 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #000066;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #9999ff;
}

#header {
  background-color: #9999ff;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 9px 9px 0 0;
  font-size: large;
}

#game {
  background-color: #f0f0f5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 9px 9px;
}

#game>p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #0000b3;
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#div_res {
  border: 1px solid #40406b;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #800000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <p id="header">Zgadnij liczbę z zakresu od 0-50</p>
    <div id="game">
      <p>Ilość prób</p>
      <input type="number" name="prob" id="prob" value=10>
      <p>Podaj liczbę</p>
      <input type="number" name="liczba" id="liczba">
      <button onclick="check()">Sprawdź</button>
      <button onclick="giveUp()">Poddaję się</button>
      <div id="div_res">
        <p id="res"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm facing an issue with the end of the game logic. The game is supposed to end either when the user correctly guesses the number or when they run out of attempts. However, even when the correct number is guessed, the game does not recognize the victory, and the message "Koniec gry" (End of the game) is not displayed.

In the JavaScript section, I have a function called **`check()`** that compares the user's input with the randomly generated number (**`liczba`**). If the guess is correct, the game should end and display a "Wygrałeś" (You won) message. However, the game doesn't recognize the correct guess, and the "Koniec gry" (End of the game) message is displayed prematurely.

I'd appreciate any help in identifying and resolving this issue. Thank you!

I'd appreciate any help in identifying and resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: I output the liczba variable to the console: `console.log(liczba);`
Enter this number and get "Wygrales".
You wrote that: If the guess is correct, the game should end and display a "Wygrałeś". "Koniec gry" (End of the game) message is displayed prematurely. Could you explain more specifically that "Wygrałeś" or "Koniec gry" should  displayed?